# Embedded Signing View Docusign returning 404

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am trying to get the embedded signing view to redirect my user so they can sign the document. Everytime I make the request I get a 404 with no message. There is nothing with the response other than the HTTP code. Sending the envelope works completely fine, I get an email everytime I try to test this.

```
$data = json_encode(array(
  "returnUrl" => base_url() . "dashboard/home",
  "authenticationMethod" => "email",
  "email" => $this->userEmail,
  "userName" => "seller",
  "clientUserId" => $this->user,
  'recipientId' => '1'
));


$ch = curl_init($this->baseUrl . "/envelope/$this->envelopeId/views/recipient");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
  'X-DocuSign-Authentication: ' . $this->header
  )
);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

if ($status != 201) {
  error_log($resp);
  die();
}

$response = json_decode($resp, true);
return $response['url'];
```

I have followed the examples on Docusign's documentation and even have this working in another section, this just uses composite templates instead. I tried searching for the Embedded Signing returning a 404 but found nothing. I would attach the error message but all it gives is that its receiving a 404. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled **envelopes**

```
$ch = curl_init($this->baseUrl . "/envelope/$this->envelopeId/views/recipient");
```

should be

```
$ch = curl_init($this->baseUrl . "/envelopes/$this->envelopeId/views/recipient");
```

The url for the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) should be of the following format.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

For example, if you are using the Sandbox environment then you will have to do a HTTP POST to the following url

`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`

Comment: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1902587/envelope/f688429c-3fa2-4535-9c11-c1d9885b0c57/views/recipient 

This is the URL that is constructed from 
    `$this->baseUrl . "/envelope/$this->envelopeId/views/recipient"`

Comment: Wow, it was a spelling mistake. I put it as envelope instead of envelopes in the URL....